# c# Checking if string is HtmlDecode

Tags: c#

I have this string that I am sometimes double encoding it because it is coming from two different fields. I have build this method that will do a string StringComparison. It seems complicated wanted to know if there is a better way to do something like this.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str1 = "This string is already encode &lt;0.1";

            Console.WriteLine(HTTPEncodeString(str1));


            string str2 = "This string needs to be encoded <0.01";
            Console.WriteLine(HTTPEncodeString(str2));

        }

        public static string HTTPEncodeString(string source) 
        {
            if (EncodeText(source))
            {
                return source;


            }
            else
            {
                return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(source);
            }


        }

        public static bool EncodeText(string val)
        {
            string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(val);
            string encodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(decodedText);

            return encodedText.Equals(val, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decoded string stays unchanged when returned from `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`. Therefore you can do it in a single line:

```
public static string HtmlEncodeString(string text)
{
  return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text));
}
```

---

The following shows a refactoring of your approach. Notice the changes in names to something more meaningful:

```
public static string HtmlEncodeString(string text)
{
  return IsHtmlEncoded(text) ? text : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
}

public static bool IsHtmlEncoded(string text)
{
  return !text.Equals(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Is also uses, that the result of decoding an encoded text is different from the text itself, while the result of decoding a decoded text is equal to the text. In this way you can avoid a least one call to `HtmlEncode()`

Comment: There are decoded strings that are not invariant under decoding - see my answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight: you're right. Bad answer.

Comment: @Jefferson: You should remove your acceptance of this answer, because it's not right.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a language I know, but there appears to be a problem with the logic.

Suppose I have a simple statement:

> `In XML, ampersand can be represented using '&amp;' or '&#38;'`

Is that an already-encoded string?  The logic here says that it is, but we see that's not the case - the HTML version of that would be

> `In XML, ampersand can be represented using '&amp;amp;' or '&amp;#38;'`

If it's hard to keep track in code, a better option might be a small class to hold a HTML-encoded string, so that we don't confuse these with content strings (or vice-versa, if HTML-encoded is the default in your target environment).

But TBH, I think that good variable naming should be enough to track which strings are which.

Comment: what would the class look like? would it be a bunch of nested replaces

Comment: Thanks @Henrik: it's been a while since I've hand-written a CREF value!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend on Toby's excellent post.

You shouldn't be using/needing a stop gap mechanism like this.

Data you are working with should never be HTML-encoded and there should never be any need  for you to encoding it yourself with `HtmlEncode`. Any and all HTML-encoding should happen as late as possible, namely automatically in the template engine used (I believe in C# by default this would be in the Razor templates).

If you do have data that is already HTML-encoded make sure to keep it separate from any other data and use the "raw html" function of the template engine to output it. However you need to KNOW (do NOT assume!) that that HTML doesn't contain any malicious code.

If you have data (for example from a third party) of which you do not know if it HTML-encoded or not, then you preferable should assume it is not encoded and let it be HTML-encoded by the template engine when it is output, even if that results in double encoded HTML. Also you need to make sure that everyone involved (the third party, your boss, etc.) knows that this is a dangerous situation, that needs to be addressed.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have a field in the database that is storing HTML like <B> and <I> tags. I also have data in the same field that is &lt;50. So it is both encode and decode

Comment: @Jefferson: No, that data would be considered already HTML-encoded. No need to encode/decode it. Keep it separate, validate that it actually contains what you assume (for example, by using a HTML cleaner/sanitizer library) and output it as "raw html".